# Google Sheets auto populate timestamp in a cell when a particular value is entered in any other cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm using work tracker in Google Sheets. I have columns from A to U. I have "Status" in "L" column with drop down options - **Inquiry Status Pending, Reconciliation Done, Waiting for IM Response**. When I set the Status to "Inquiry Status Pending" I want timestamp to be populated in "N" column and it should be static. Like wise - for Reconciliation Done, timestamp should be in "E" column. For "Waiting for IM Response" status, timestamp should be in "R" column. All timestamps should be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The best way to insert a timestamp on edit event is a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Apps Script offers many useful functions to [work with Google spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). It also contains [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) like `onEdit` that fire when an edit takes place in your spreadsheet and allow you retrieve the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) (useful for determining e.g. the edited column). The best way to become familiar with Apps Script is following the official [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1/#0).

How to implement your request in Apps Script:

1. Go from your spreadsheet on `Tools -> Script editor`
2. Paste the script bellow
3. Save the script and click on the "play button" (to run the script)
4. Ignore the error message you receive. You script now works correctly.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('edited');
  if (column == 12){
    var timestamp = new Date();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var value = e.value;
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    Logger.log("edited cell: "+range.getA1Notation());
    if( value == "Inquiry Status Pending"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 14).setValue(timestamp);
    } else if(value == "Reconciliation Done"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(timestamp);
    } else if(value == "Waiting for IM Response"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 18).setValue(timestamp);
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend you to spend some time to study Apps Script so you understand how the provided code works and can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm receiving error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: As mentioned in point 4. : Just ignore this error message :-) It is caused by the fact that if you run your script manually, the event object `e` is not defined. Your script will work regardless - try it out by changing a value in your status column!

Comment: Glad to hear it!